# perl match nested regex and write back to file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a txt file and I would like to match a certain pattern and convert a numeric field from decimal to hex and write back existing file using perl.

**Before**

```
Wins {
  XYZ: 8,  SCHOOL1, SCHOOL2;
  ABC: 1,  SCHOOL4, SCHOOL4;
}

Losses {
  XYZABC: 100, SCHOOL1, 4 {
  IPQSAP, 2;
}

  EFGHIJ: 200, SCHOOL2, 9 {
  IBQCAP, 2;
}
}
```

**After**

```
TEST_version = "1_1.0";

Wins {
  XYZ: 8, SCHOOL1, SCHOOL2;
  ABC: 1, SCHOOL4, SCHOOL4;
}

Losses {
  XYZABC: 0x64, SCHOOL1, 4 {
  IPQSAP, 2;
}

  EFGHIJ: 0xC8, SCHOOL2, 9 {
  IBQCAP, 2;

}
}
```

In the above example under pattern `Losses {` and after pattern `XYZABC:` , `EFGHIJ:` or `any other pattern containing alphanumeric value:` match check if next value is numeric and is decimal if so convert to hexadecimal

I am trying for something like below pattern but not able to convert and write to new file.

```
if (/Losses {/)
   if ( /(\w+):\s*(\w+),\s*(\w+),\s*(\w+)/ ) {
    
        if ($2 =~ /0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/)
        {
         //Value is already in Hexadecimal
        } elsif($2 =~ /[0-9]+/) {
            print("\n Decimal");
            my $hex = sprintf("0x%02X", $2);
            print(" Hex equivalent = $hex");  
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: The rest of your script would be helpful. For instance, you mention that this should only happen in the `Losses` block, but the code you pasted ignores this aspect.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This file seems to be of certain format, if that's consistent I'd write subroutines to extract the different values within the named parentheses with much simpler regexes (and ideally `split` where possible) and manipulate that data then write it out rather than try to have a few big regexes and parse the contents top-down

Comment: Recct do you have any examples or samples to show the approach ?

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge with a regex approach is the nested braces. There is a module available to handle that called [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced). The `extract_bracketed` function in **Text::Balanced** lets you specify the type of brackets you need to parse. The tricky part is getting the regex expression for the prefix correct. My example demonstrates this with two expressions: the first one fails.

If you don't have the regex correct or there is another issue, 'extract_bracketed' writes errors to `$@`. It is set to `undef` if there are no errors.

Once you have extracted the losses section you can use a simple regex to find and convert the decimal number to hex. I used the ['e' modifier](https://perlmaven.com/regex-superpowers-execute-code-in-substitution) to evaluate an [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) expression to handle the conversion to hex.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Balanced 'extract_bracketed';

# slurp the file contents.
# local $/ sets the record seperator to undef within the block.
# <DATA> will then read the whole file. 

my $file_contents = do { local $/; <DATA> };

#               These prefixes are regex patterns for 'extract_bracketed'.
my @prefix_paterns = ( 
                        '.*Losses ',      # The '.' doesn't match newlines so
                                          # this doesn't match anything.
                        '(?s).*Losses ',  # (?s) lets '.' match newlines.
                     );

foreach my $prefix (@prefix_paterns){
    my ($extracted, $remainder, $prefix_match) = extract_bracketed(
                                                           $file_contents, 
                                                           '{}', 
                                                           $prefix );

    # 'extract_bracketed' writes errors to $@. It is undef if no error.
    if (length($@)){
        print "Error: $@\n\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Extracted:\n$extracted\n";
        print '-'x75, "\n";
        #                     
        # The 'e' modifier causes the substitution operator to evaluate the 
        #    expression in the second position.
        #
        # If the number is already in hex format it won't match the regex (\d+).
        #
        $extracted =~ s/(\w+:\s*)(\d+)/sprintf "%s%#x", $1, $2/eg;
        print "Modified:\n$prefix_match$extracted$remainder\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
Wins {
  XYZ: 8,  SCHOOL1, SCHOOL2;
  ABC: 1,  SCHOOL4, SCHOOL4;
}

Losses {
  XYZABC: 100, SCHOOL1, 4 {
  IPQSAP, 2;
}

  EFGHIJ: 200, SCHOOL2, 9 {
  IBQCAP, 2;
}
}

Draws {}
```

I added the 'Draws' section to your sample data to demonstrate that extract_bracketed will extract the part we want in the middle of the file.

The output from this script looks like this:

```
Error: Did not find prefix: /.*Losses /, detected at offset 0

Extracted:
{
  XYZABC: 100, SCHOOL1, 4 {
  IPQSAP, 2;
}

  EFGHIJ: 200, SCHOOL2, 9 {
  IBQCAP, 2;
}
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modified:
Wins {
  XYZ: 8,  SCHOOL1, SCHOOL2;
  ABC: 1,  SCHOOL4, SCHOOL4;
}

Losses {
  XYZABC: 0x64, SCHOOL1, 4 {
  IPQSAP, 2;
}

  EFGHIJ: 0xc8, SCHOOL2, 9 {
  IBQCAP, 2;
}
}

Draws {}
```